# Java program hangs

Tags: java

made a short java program in Bluej upon compiling it and trying to get it to run it, it hangs with no output.
I've had this issue before when using the in.next function.
Regards for any help and my apologies for what may seem a simple question.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class net_salary{

public static void main(String[]args){

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



float income;
float incometax;
float afterincometax;
float nationalinsurance;
float afterni;
float pension;
float netincome;

income = in.nextFloat();





if(income <9000)
    {
      incometax = 0;
      afterincometax = income - incometax;

    }
    else if (income >=9000 && income <=21000)
    {
        incometax = (income * 0.15F);
        afterincometax = income - incometax;
    }

    else if (income >=21000 && income<=31000)
    {
        incometax = income * 0.2F;
        afterincometax = income - incometax;

    }

    else if (income >=31000 &&  income<=50000)
    {
        incometax = income * 0.225F;
        afterincometax = income - incometax;
    }

    else
    {
        incometax = income * 0.25F;
        afterincometax = income - incometax;
    }





   if(income < 16000)

   {
       nationalinsurance = 0;
       afterni = income - nationalinsurance;

    }


    else if(income >= 16000 && income <= 31000)
        {

            nationalinsurance = income*0.05F;
            afterni = income - nationalinsurance;
        }
    else if(income > 31000 && income <=40000)
        {

            nationalinsurance = income*0.09F;
            afterni = income - nationalinsurance;
        }
    else
        {

            nationalinsurance = income*0.11F;
            afterni = income - nationalinsurance;
        }





   pension = income *0.05F;

   netincome = ((income - pension)-nationalinsurance)-incometax;

   System.out.println("Your gross income is : £" + income) ;
   System.out.println("Your income tax is : £" + incometax) ;
   System.out.println("Your nationalinsurance  £" + nationalinsurance) ;
   System.out.println("Your pension is : £" + pension) ;
   System.out.println("Your net income is : £" + netincome) ;

}

}
```

Comment: Define "not happy".  Do you get any messages?

Comment: My apologies should have been more clear, it dosn't actually run the program but rather 'hangs' and i have to manually terminate it. Nothing comes up etc.

Comment: It **runs** just fine for me, as long as I enter a valid `float` value.

Comment: It doesn't like the fact that your income tax calc is wrong. You only pay the higher rate of tax on the portion of your income over the threshold. ;-)

Comment: Even though there actually isn't a real problem here ... if there was, that's what debuggers are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue you are having is. When I run it, it works just fine. It took me a second to realize that it was waiting for user input, but once I figured that out I just typed in a number, hit enter, and it worked. If I were you I would add a prompt to the user, something like:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your income: ");
income = in.nextFloat();
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice helped a lot to have a prompt.

Comment: @HertenFerford - Glad to have helped! If you got your question answered, it is good practice on StackOverflow to accept the answer that helped you do it. That is the best way of showing gratitude. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is asking for a `float` value and is waiting for you to input one.
Try adding:
`System.out.println("Enter a value:");`
just before
`income = in.nextFloat();`
to make this fact more apparent.

Then just enter a float value, like `5`, and press "Enter".

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue - for some reason it was refusing to bring up the terminal and when typing it produced an error - however adding in this code solved the issue.

Comment: I think there is a setting to always display the terminal in BlueJ. You may want to look into this to prevent this issue from happening again (or always include a prompt!).

Comment: To be fair, I don't believe that the original poster has enough reputation to accept answers, yet. I remember needing something like 15 reputation before I could accept answers.

Comment: Aye i would vote it up if i could but alas i can't until my feedback is up. I've accepted the post as helpful but I'm not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't prompt for anything before reading stdin, so just enter a number and hit return and it runs.

Comment: Cheers for your advice, for some reason the program was refusing to open a terminal however putting in a prompt seemed to resolve this swiftly. My Regards.

Comment: It wasn't "refusing to open a terminal".  It's a terminal program, you need to run it from a command line.